# Difference between "regarder" and "voir"

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

Is there a difference (big or small?) between “regarder” and “voir”? In what context would “regarder” be used instead of “voir” and vice versa? Or, does it not matter?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*Voir* is passive (“see”) and *regarder* is active (“look at”).

Comment: So, I would say: "Je vois un film" rather than "Je regarde un film"?

Comment: Usually *on regarde un film*. But in very specific contexts it could be voir. *Que font-ils là-bas ? – Je ne sais pas, je vois un film…*. *Watch* is generally *regarder* when it's not *surveiller*.

Comment: I'd use "watch" to translate "regarder" here :).

Answer (score 3):

Do you understand the difference between *look* and *see* in English? If so:

- *regarder*: look, look at, or watch, depending on the context
- *voir*: see

(Similar to the difference between *listen* or *listen to* and *hear*.)

Answer (score 2):

Selon le Robert :

> - VOIR : du latin *videre* : Percevoir les images des objets par le sens
>     de la vue.
>   Percevoir quelque chose par les yeux.
> - REGARDER : de
>     *re-* et *garder* : "Veiller, prendre garde à" : Faire en sorte de voir, s'appliquer à voir.

Je vois, je perçois des images, je suis réceptif, en attente :

> Je traverse la rue, car *j'ai vu* qu'il n'y avait pas de danger (ou
>   que la circulation est arrêtée).

Je regarde, j'utilise mes yeux pour chercher, pour comprendre :

> *Je regarde* la vitrine de ce magasin (on dit couramment *"[Je fais du lèche vitrine](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/l%C3%A8che-vitrine)"*) car je recherche une paire de chaussure à la mode.

Si je vais *voir* un film (je ne l'ai pas vu, donc je ne peux le regarder,  porter une attention sur ce que mes yeux ne perçoivent pas [encore]) , c'est pour *le regarder* (car alors je verrai ce film et je pourrai chercher le message du réalisateur, observer le jeu des acteurs, apprécier la bande son, ..).